# Codeigniter MYController bit being executed

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am new to codeigniter and rusty in coding

MY_Controller does not seem to be executed, please help

Comment: Could You please provide more information about Your specific problem?

Answer (score 0):

Open the application/config/config.php file with a text editor and
set your base URL. Should look like this:

```
 $config['base_url']    = "your_address/your_controller/"
```

If using local host it'd be something like:

```
$config['base_url'] = "localhost/my_controller/"
```

If that doesn't work go to your application/config/routes.php and change your default controller name to the your controller's name:

```
$route['default_controller'] = "my_controller";
```

If that doesn't work ensure your controller is located in your controllers file and is named correctly (I'm assuming your controller is called MY_Controller...should be lower case, I'm pretty sure there's a rule on that).

Then ensure the Class name is the same as the file name and that it extends CI_Controller:

```
class my_controller extends CI_Controller{//controller functions here}
```

References:

- [CI Introduction Tutorial](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/installation/index.html)
- [CI controllers tutorial](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/controllers.html)